# Android activity with FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL flag on top of home screen

Tags: android

I am having an android activity with FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODALset. 
My activity is translucent and not full screen.
I just want to by-pass the touch events outside my activity window boundary to the underlying activity.

I am able to by-pass the event successfully so that i can scroll the underlying activity when my activity is on top of it.

My problem is, When my activity is on top of the "Applications List" Screen, i am not able to launch any application from the list. But I can scroll the list and the icon of the selected application is getting highlighted when selected. But it is not getting launched.

But when my activity with FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL is on top of the home screen (where we see wallpaper) the applications can be launched when user clicks on the shortcut icons

Please help me with this issue.

Thanks in advance.
Pragadeesh

Comment: Did you find the reason for that? I am facing exactly the same issue

Comment: No @Mak.. I couldn't find the reason yet.