# Android: How to touch underlying activity

Tags: android, events, view, android-activity, touch

I have an activity with a GoogleMaps component. It's a linear layout with size to wrap_content and translucent style. The Map is the only ui element and has a fixed size. How can the touch events outside the Map be delegated to the underlying activity?

Any hints appreciated!
Marcus

Comment: this question seems to be pretty close: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338951/android-activity-with-flag-not-touch-modal-flag-on-top-of-home-screen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can't. Only one `Activity` can be active at a time. The underlying `Activity` may be visible because of the translucent theme of the active one, but it is [paused](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle) so it won't react to
any touch event.

Use fragments or a combination of layout in a single `Activity`

Comment: If I flag it as FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE, it stays on top and the underlying activity receives the events. Thats almost pretty close?

Comment: Not sure. But the doc says FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL will redirect the touch to the window behind it so it may work.